# Convexity in functional space for GANs

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, functional-calculus

In the paper: [Generative Adversarial Nets](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2014/file/5ca3e9b122f61f8f06494c97b1afccf3-Paper.pdf), on Page 5 Proposition 2 Proof, the authors claim that equation (3) is convex in p_g. I am trying to understand how are the authors arriving at that conclusion. Any intuitions will be helpful.

Comment: This equation is linear in $p_g$. Linear maps are convex.